# Koppeln und Verbinden

Tags: german-to-english, standard-german

Mir ist der Unterschied nicht klar zwischen:

> ich verband den Laptop mit dem Bluetooth

und

> ich koppelte den Laptop mit dem Bluetooth.

Kann mir das bitte jemand erklären!

Comment: Finde ich beides unglücklich formuliert. "Ich verband/koppelte den Laptop über/via/mittels Bluetooth" aber "Ich verband/koppelte den Laptop mit dem Smartphone".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Im technischen Umfeld von Bluetooth ist das eine (koppeln) eine Voraussetzung für das andere (verbinden).

Damit sich 2 Geräte mittels Bluetooth verbinden können, muss man sie vorher koppeln.

Beim "Koppeln" werden die Geräte sich gegenseitig bekannt gemacht: typischerweise startet man den Kopplungsvorgang durch irgendeine Taste oder eine Einstellung auf beiden Geräten. Dadurch tauschen die Geräte ihre "Identitäten" aus, und erkennen sich später automatisch wieder.

Nachdem zwei Geräte gekoppelt sind, können sie jederzeit wieder ohne weiteren Kopplungsvorgang miteinander verbunden werden.
Das passiert meist automatisch, wenn die Geräte sich in Reichweite befinden und -bei bestimmten Bluetootharten wie z.B. Lautsprechern oder Tastaturen- noch nicht mit anderen Geräten verbunden sind.

Comment: Schöne Ironie: Eine Frage zu *Koppeln* und *Verbinden* wird von jemandem beantwortet, der *Link* heißt :-)

Comment: Ich habe meinen Namen zum Beruf gemacht, weil mit dem Nachnamen nicht Informatiker zu werden, ist ja sträflich

Comment: Naja, Butler hättest Du damit auch werden können *grins*

Comment: Jetzt reicht es aber mit den schlechten Namens- Assoziationen ;)

Answer (score 3):

"Verbinden" ist allgemeiner als "koppeln". Wenn man zwei Dinge "verbindet", stellt man generell eine Verbindung zwischen den Dingen her. Das alleine sagt noch nichts über die weiteren Eigenschaften der Verbindung aus.

Wenn man zwei Dinge "koppelt", sagt man damit in der Regel etwas mehr über die Eigenschaften der Verbindung aus. Die Verbindung ist dann in der Regel reversibel (sie kann wieder gelöst werden), und die Verbindung ist an dieser Stelle vorgesehen.

Comment: Danke sehr für die Erklärung!